# Django - overiding get_fieldset in ModelAdmin returns a field twice

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add a field to the admin fieldset manually.

The function `calcGeometryField` returns the field I want to add to the admin fieldset.

However, I got the field added twice in the admin interface. Why?

```
class FeatureAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Info', {'fields':['shapefile', 'id_relat', 'attribute_value']})
    ]
    list_display = ['shapefile', 'id_relat']
    list_filter = ('shapefile', ('shapefile__created_by'))

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(FeatureAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        fieldsets[0][1]['fields'].insert(2, calcGeometryField(obj.shapefile.geom_type))
        return fieldsets
```

Note: The field is a map geodjango from OSMGeoAdmin, but I tested with an IntegerField with the same results.

**Edit: It seems also that fielsets are mixed when changing model instances. Fields from an instance appear in another instance in the admin interface.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original fieldsets dict is a class-level attribute. By inserting your field, you're modifying the class-level dictionary, which affects all instances derived from it.

You might want to do a deepcopy of the fieldset before inserting:

```
import copy
...
fieldsets = copy.deepcopy(super(FeatureAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))
```